# 504 Gateway Timeout when requesting access token by refresh grant

Tags: social-tables

I get the authorization code, use this to request a refresh token, and am attempting (with the rails 'oauth2' gem) to request the access token. While the refresh token request receives a response, my request for an access token receives a 504.

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, { :site => DOMAIN, :token_url => PATH_TOKEN })
token = client.get_token({:grant_type => 'refresh_token', :refresh_token => token_by,
:client_id => CLIENT_ID, :client_secret => CLIENT_SECRET})
```

The debug information on my side that I'm able to see is:

> I, [2018-04-26T12:35:20.413570 #25141]  INFO -- : post
>   https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/oauth/token D,
>   [2018-04-26T12:35:20.413691 #25141] DEBUG -- request: User-Agent:
>   "Faraday v0.11.0" Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" I,
>   [2018-04-26T12:35:20.413792 #25141]  INFO -- Status: 504 D,
>   [2018-04-26T12:35:20.413935 #25141] DEBUG -- response: date: "Thu, 26
>   Apr 2018 16:35:20 GMT" content-type: "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
>   content-length: "0" connection: "close" access-control-allow-origin:
>   "*" vary: "Origin" st-request-id:
>   "d9bb4647-279d-4998-b5a8-28b5046f0ea1#180873755"
>   x-kong-upstream-latency: "30217"  x-kong-proxy-latency: "0" via:
>   "kong/0.9.8"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain how the rails oauth2 gem works, but in general, it should make an api call to `https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/oauth/token"` which will return both the access_token and the `refresh_token` in the same response object.

Answer (score 0):

if u had got authorization code, then you can do following to fetch access token:

```
require 'oauth2'

client = OAuth2::Client.new('client_id', 'client_secret', :site => 'https://example.org')
token = client.auth_code.get_token('authorization_code_value', :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback')
```

you can try this.